# Receive two inputs in C language

Tags: c

I want a program that can get two integers from user and put the sum of those inputs in a variable, after that checks that is sum more than 5 or not ? (I know I can do it with if , ... but I want to do it with while). I myself did it but it has some problems, would you mind saying what is the problem and how can I debug it ? Here is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int ui1;
    int ui2;
    puts("Please enter two numbers:");
    scanf("%2i", &ui1, &ui2);
    int sum;
    sum = ui1+ui2;
    while(sum > 5) { 
         printf("Whats up !");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: edited, please look again.

Comment: scanf format argument should be "%i %i", not "%2i" which denotes two-digit integer.

Comment: To debug one should use GDB, simply type gdb <program binary> and then type start. `next` will make the next line of the program run and you can type `print a` to print the value of a.

Comment: `while` and `if` are not interchangeable. Your code will print `Whats up !` infinitely when the sum is larger than 5.

Comment: ... although you can make that work with a `while` by adding a `break;` after the print. But there's no point to doing it that way - just use the `if`.

Comment: @sharif It is not part of the mandate of SO to enforce academic honesty. As long as the question holds up on merit (which most homework questions don't), comments such as yours are nonconstructive. If you disagree answering homework questions, it's best to either flag/downvote if they have quality issues, or move on if they don't.

Comment: @RamchandraApte - Your suggestion of using GDB assumes the OP is using GNU.   The system being used may have a different set of debug tools built in.  Not everyone uses the same environment :)

Comment: @ryyker ah, I keep forgetting about Windows/Mac users ☺

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that i got what you want to do... but if you simply want to check the sum of the two integers using the while statement, you can put a break inside the while loop and everything will work :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int ui1;
    int ui2;
    puts("Please enter two numbers:");
    scanf("%2i", &ui1, &ui2);
    int sum;
    sum = ui1+ui2;
    while(sum > 5) { 
         printf("Whats up !");
         break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As others told you, using a if is the best solution

Answer (score 6):

This line is only scanning for 1 integer (`%i` with a `2` format, indicating only take 2 digits.):

```
scanf("%2i", &ui1, &ui2);
```

But it seems you expected to receive two integers.
This will leave the second argument, `ui2`, uninitialized.
(It should fill `ui1` successfully, at least)

Try instead:

```
scanf("%i %i",  &ui1, &ui2);
```

Comment: To elaborate on abelenky's answer, which is eminently correct, please consult section 7.4 in K&R 2'nd ed.

Answer (score 2):

Try including the scanf statement into the loop, it will no longer be an infinite loop... (also need to dereference the integers, see EDIT)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int ui1;
    int ui2;
    puts("Please enter two numbers:\n");
    //scanf("%2i", &ui1, &ui2);
    int sum = 10;//(so that it will enter the loop at least once)
    //sum = ui1+ui2;
    while(sum > 4) 
    { 
        printf("enter number 1:\n");
        scanf("%i", &ui1); //EDIT &
        printf("enter number 2:\n");
        scanf("%i", &ui2); //EDIT &
        sum = ui1+ui2;        
    }
    printf("result is:  %d\n", sum);
    getchar();//so you can see the result;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can I ask the down voter the reason for the down vote please?  The code works and illustrates an answer that addresses the OP question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset the "sum", because otherwise the while loop will be true FOREVER.
Second the input scanf is simply wrong.

Here the correct code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int ui1;
    int ui2;
    puts("Please enter two numbers:");
    scanf("%d %d", &ui1, &ui2);
    int sum;
    sum = ui1+ui2;
    while(sum > 4) { printf("Whats up !");
    sum=0;}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your loop will still run forever. Not to mention you still only read one integer.

Comment: oh you right . how can I stop it ? or start the program again ?

Comment: You can put another set of `scanf(,);` and `sum = ui1+ui2;` statement series into the while loop, that way the values for ui1 and ui2 will be updated, and the loop will no longer be infinite.

Comment: I don't know, I edited it, but seems to be it doesn't save the edit

Comment: @GianfrancoCostamagna - This ***[LIST](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)*** may indicate the reason your edit is not taking.

Answer (score 1):

**Actually while is a loop stmt not a conditional checker**

**if you want conditional checker  use if...else series , switch etc**

**Note:** *in your code loop starts if (sum > 5) and never ends (infinate "Whats up !")*

```
sum = ui1+ui2;
while(sum > 5)  ///loop starts if (sum > 5) and never ends (infinate "Whats up !")
{ 
     printf("Whats up !"); // (infinate "Whats up !")
}

  if(sum > 5)

  {

  //greater stuff
  }

   else

{

   //lower stuff
}
```

**See Tutorial Here** [conditionals Stmts](http://www.mochima.com/tutorials/conditionals.html)